# What type of parameter is mdDeviceStatusInactive, mdDeviceStatusUnexported etc...

Tags: java, snmp, sigar

I would like to get some information with java in windows about following parameters:

1) mdDeviceStatusInactive
2) mdDeviceStatusUnexported
3) dbhDLNToPNDanger 
4} dhbPNToStorageDanger

If anybody know about this please explain about these parameters in brief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) mdDeviceStatusInactive 2) mdDeviceStatusUnexported 3) dbhDLNToPNDanger 4} dhbPNToStorageDanger

above parameters looks realated to any storage array. And if you'll see first 2 parameters then u realize both data-type should be boolean.

1) mdDeviceStatusInactive:- This parameter is telling like mdDevice status is Inactive or not.
2) mdDeviceStatusUnexported:- This parameter is telling like mdDevice status is Unexported or not.

And may be rest of the parameters also have data-type as boolean only.